# Macos terminal can't find homebrew

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew

As the below shows, I seem to have homebrew in my path, can be called if I reference the executable directly, but if I try and use just `brew`, then bash can't find it. What could be causing this?

```sh
max@Maxwells-MacBook-Air:~$ echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew:/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/bin:/Users/max/.nvm/versions/node/v16.2.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/max/flutter/bin
max@Maxwells-MacBook-Air:~$ brew --version
-bash: brew: command not found
max@Maxwells-MacBook-Air:~$ /opt/homebrew/bin/brew --version
Homebrew 3.2.0
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 3d5d1ec33b; last commit 2021-06-29)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision ed99f34e4d; last commit 2021-06-30)
max@Maxwells-MacBook-Air:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$PATH` supports only directories, not files. Therefore, set your path to

```
PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
```

instead of

```
PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin/brew:$PATH"
```